# Unable to pass array data from parent to child in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to do a simple task of passing data from parent to child. The data is an array nested inside another array.

parent.component.html

```
    <div *ngFor="let parent of parentArray; index as mainIdx" class="main-container" #mainDiv>
      <button (click)="addChild(mainIdx)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      <button (click)="addSibling(mainIdx)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      <button (click)="removeSibling(mainIdx)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <app-child  *ngFor="let child of parent.childArray" [childData]="parent.childArray"></app- 
      child>
     </div>
```

parent.component.ts

```
addChild(parentIndex: number){
  
   let childId: number;
  if(this.parentArray[pIndex].childArray === undefined){
     this.parentArray[pIndex]['childArray'] = [];
     this.parentArray[pIndex].childArray.push({id: 0})
  }
  else{
    childId =  this.parentArray[pIndex].childArray.length;
    this.parentArray[pIndex].childArray.push({id: childId})
  }
 }
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input() childData: any[];
    
   ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.childData);
  }

   addGrandChild(){
    this.childAdded = true;
  }
```

child.component.html

```
  <div class="child-container">
    <button (click)="addGrandChild()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    <button (click)="removeChild()"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    <app-child *ngIf="childAdded"></app-child>
</div>
```

Basically what I am trying to do here is generate a tree like structure for dynamically generated children and grandchildren. The parent can have a sibling and can have children, these children can have grandchildren and the grandchildren can also have children and so on. I am able to generate the components but I see that no data is being passed from the parent to the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ngOnChanges

```js
ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges): void {
  console.log(change.childData.currentValue);
}
```